# ... the Future or Future

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

I am trying to answer [this](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/64914/how-to-motivate-students-you-supervise-to-produce-high-quality-research-when-oth/64939#64939) question asked in acaemia.SE. In my [answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/64939/24064), I have 3 subtitles as follows. Which of the two {alternatives} are grammatically correct?

1. Anxieties of {the Future} or {Future}.
2. Anxieties of {the Past} or
   {Past}.
3. Anxieties of {the Present} or {Present}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In such expressions you should use "of **the**" beside the fact we could easily understand, you're dealing of anxieties of/about *the* time ; so you want to use **the** to mark precisely it's a *noun*.

Comment: Your answer got me reading [this article](http://academia.stackexchange.com/a/64939/24064). Lack of technical knowledge, one of the culprits of learning English by movies :).

Comment: I dig it ! As I saw yesterday a movie "Pompeii" where I'm sure I heard a "me either" instead of "me too"... But when I watch Irish films, I put on subtitles for deaf & read :)